# How to make LDAP attribute to accept json value

Tags: ldap

We are using apache directory studio to connect to LDAP

Actually We are in development phase of our application, so as part of preparing LDAP schema, we need one attribute value syntax to be json, so for that do I get directly "Json" under syntaxes or how?

Please let me know, thanks in advance

Comment: what is your use case for this? I don't know of a JSON syntax but you could base64 encode the value and store it in a DirectorysString attribute; that would preserve it nicely and avoid any encoding issues. Again, not sure of your use case but have you considered using something like the Forgerock REST2LDAP?

Answer (score 0):

Like [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4187346/dave-bennett) said.
And although you did not mention which LDAP server, but regardless any attribute with a Syntax of [binary](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2252.txt) should work too.

-jim